# How to fix error with train_test_split in Python?

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.array([0.1,0.2,0.7,8.0,45.0,56.0,66.0,0.7,0.6,64.0])
y=np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1])
x = np.array(x).reshape((1, -1))
y = np.array(y).reshape((1, -1))
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,test_size=0.4,         train_size=0.5, random_state=7, stratify=y)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(y_train, x_train)
y_train_predict = knn.predict(x_train)
y_test_predict = knn.predict(x_test)
print(y_train_predict)
print(y_test_predict)
```

Error:

> With n_samples=1, test_size=0.4 and train_size=0.5, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.

Comment: You can call the train_test_split function before the reshaping of the arrays

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 x = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)
 y = np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: He wrote reshape(1,-1) instead of (-1,1).